# creating new columns from combined rows through union

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having a Table Like this in Bigquery

```
**Table WriteOps**
BatchId InstanceId    Date                            Type    WriteOpsVal
C3x73d   demo1        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Write      100
C3x73d   demo2        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Write      200
E34d38   show1        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Write      300
QE4xe3   demo1        2020-07-30 17:30:06.274 UTC     Write      300

**Table ReadOps**
BatchId  InstanceId.  Date                            Type    ReadOpsVal
C3x73d   demo1        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       500
C3x73d   demo2        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       600
E34d38   show1        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       600
QE4xe3   demo1        2020-07-30 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       600
C3x73d   demo1        2020-07-27 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       100
C3x73d   demo2        2020-07-27 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       100
C3x73d   demo3        2020-07-27 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       100
C3x73d   demo3        2020-07-26 17:30:06.274 UTC     Read       100
```

I want to combine all values(WriteOpsVal,ReadOpsVal) for the particular InstanceId based on the BatchId and Date in one row. Both the tables have different no of rows.

Like this

```
Table Result 
BatchId. InstanceId    Date                               WriteOpsVal ReadOpsVal
C3x73d   demo1        2020-07-31 17:30:06.274 UTC         100           500
C3x73d   demo3        2020-07-27 17:30:06.274 UTC                       100
C3x73d   demo3        2020-07-26 17:30:06.274 UTC                       100
```

I have tried case statement like

```
with WriteOps as (select ...),
ReadOps as (select ....),
Unite as(select * from WriteOps UNION ALL select * from ReadOps)
select batchId,InstanceId,Date,case Type when "Write" then (select WriteOpsVal from WriteOps where batchId=Unite.batchId and InstanceId=Unite.InstanceId and Date=Unite.Date) END as WriteOpsVal, case Type when "Read" then (select ReadOpsVal from ReadOps where batchId=Unite.batchId and InstanceId=Unite.InstanceId and Date=Unite.Date) END as ReadOpsVal
```

but this does not give me the intended 1 row for 1 unique group of records and it gives me result for each table one after the other

Any idea on how to accompolish this? Thanks

Comment: You should explain the logic behind such combine action. So far it is totally not clear and any answer will be just shooting into the air. Obviously the query you presented makes not much sense if at all so does not help to understand that logic. Check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#full_outer_join) instead a UNION:

```sql
WITH WriteOps AS (select ...),
ReadOps AS (select ....)
SELECT 
 COALESCE(w.BatchId, r.BatchId) as BatchId, 
 COALESCE(w.InstanceId, r.InstanceId) as InstanceId,
 COALESCE(w.Date, r.Date) as Date, 
 w.WriteOpsVal as WriteOpsVal, 
 r.ReadOpsVal as ReadOpsVal 
FROM WriteOps w 
     FULL OUTER JOIN ReadOps r 
        ON (w.BatchId = r.BatchId AND w.InstanceId = r.InstanceId AND w.Date = r.Date)
```

Comment: Thanks Damiao Martins, IFNULL(w.BatchId, r.BatchId)  this will work for 2 columns if there is a extratable and an extra metric like WriteMaxOpsVal z then is there any alternative as IFNULL(w.BatchId,r.BatchId,z.BatchId) will not work due to the signature

Comment: @user1403505 in this case you can use `COALESCE`. I'll put in the answer. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#coalesce

Comment: exactly thats what i used, great answer